# Generate XML File with Maven

Tags: xml, templates, ant, maven

I have an XML file that looks like this...

```
<foo>
   <bar>$VALUE$</bar>
</foo>
```

Is there anyway I can merge this xml file and a .properties file using Maven or is this a task best left to Ant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resource plugin can copy with filtering, replacing a placeholder (`$VALUE$` in this case) with a property value. Here's the relevant doc: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

It should be noted that maven placeholders look like this: `${VALUE}`.

Comment: Yeah, that works in most cases. But what if `${VALUE}` is `foo < bar`? Suddenly the XML file is unparseable. Worse yet, what if `${VALUE}` contains content that _corrupts_ the data while still leaving it parseable? Taking the example in the description, imagine if `${VALUE}` were `bad value1</bar><bar>bad value 2`. Suddenly you have _two_ `<bar>` values (as an illustration). This is a security risk unless you have complete control over `VALUE`. There is no Maven XML-encode function I know of, but try surrounding the embedded value with `<![CDATA[`…`]]>`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Ant for merging and invoke the task from Maven.